# How to automatically reblog your Tumblr liked posts

Tags: tumblr, blog, if-this-then-that, automation

Is there a way to automatically reblog<sup>1</sup> the posts you like on Tumblr?

I looked into IFTTT but couldn't find the right hooks.

<sub>1. On a different Tumblr, not the default one.</sub>

Comment: This can be easily done with tumblr api. A simple php script running on openshift can do it.